# Subquery error, not allowing me to return more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Within my database I have a table called `studentEmailAddresses` and I want to take each of the email addresses and create one long string that will hold all the email addresses so it can be used within my `sp_send_dbmail` function.

For example, I have two email addresses `Test1@hotmail.com` and `Test2@hotmail.com` so at the end of subquery I want to have a result set that looks like `Test1@hotmail.com; Test2@hotmail.com;`. Below shows how I have tried to do this but I am receiving the following error message `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

```
Declare @emailList varchar (1000)
set @emailList = (Select coalesce(emailAdd + ';', ' ') 
from studentEmailAddresses)
Print @emailList
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is because  you are using `SET` for variable assignment. When assigning from a query, SET can only assign a scalar value. If the query returns multiple values/rows then SET will raise an error (as is the case here). `SELECT` will assign one of the values to the variable and hide the fact that multiple values were returned (so you'd likely never know why something was going wrong elsewhere). You can write a query as:

```
Declare @emailList varchar (1000)
SET  @emailList  = 
(select emailAdd+ ';' AS 'data()'
FROM @studentEmailAddresses 
FOR XML PATH('')  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @emailList varchar (max) = ''
Select @emailList = @emailList + emailAdd + ';' 
from studentEmailAddresses
Print @emailList
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @emailList varchar (1000) = ''
Select @emailList += coalesce(emailAdd + ';', ' ') 
from studentEmailAddresses
Print @emailList
```

Comment: There are no results being returned with the Print Statment

Comment: it was maybe because de @emailList is null by default. i edited it

Comment: nice! acept the answer if it solved your problem, pls

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @emailList varchar (1000)
SET @emailList=''
Select @emailList =@emailList +  coalesce(emailAdd + ';', ' ') 
from studentEmailAddresses
Print @emailList
```

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL Server:**

```
Declare @emailList varchar (1000)
SET @emailList=''
Select @emailList = @emailList +  coalesce(emailAdd + ';', ' ') 
from studentEmailAddresses
Print @emailList
```

**In MySQL:**

```
DECLARE emailList VARCHAR(1000);
SET emailList='';
SELECT CONCAT(emailList, emailAdd, '; ') INTO  emailList
FROM studentEmailAddresses;
SELECT emailList FROM DUAL;
```

Note that DUAL is a dummy table in MySQL or you can simply select emailList as,

```
SELECT emailList;
```

Thank you.